# How to box the last (or one) line of an aligned set of equations?

Tags: equations, align, mdframed, framed, empheq

I am trying to get the last equation in a list of aligned equations boxed, however this is more challenging than I thought it might be.  I would like to be able to do it with the box both including the equation number and without.  Below are my current simple methods for framing equations.  Any input is welcome and appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah.

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{align}
1+2&=3\\
1+2+3&=6
\end{align}
\end{mdframed}

Blah blah blah.

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
1+2&=3\\
1+2+3&=6
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathtools` package has a command to box a single equation in an alignment. Here is a way to customise this box as an `\fcolorbox`, with the help of `xpatch` and `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorboxed}[1]{\fcolorbox{DarkSeaGreen}{DarkSeaGreen!20}{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
\xpatchcmd{\@Aboxed}{\boxed}{\colorboxed}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
1+2 &=3\\
1+2+3 &=6 \\
\Aboxed{1+2+3 + 4 &=10}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's quite nice, thank you.  Do you know if that box can be extended easily to include the equation number?

Comment: *A priori*, it must not be so easy. If you use the coloured version, I would suggest a coloured equation tag (of the same colour as the frame) instead. Unrelated: I forgot  to mention that, when you load `mathtools` or `empheq`, you don't have to load `amsmath`.